# Casting to derived type problem in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, casting, box2d-iphone

I am quite new to C++, but have worked with C# for years, however it is not helping me here! :)

My problem:  I have an `Actor` class which `Ball` and `Peg` both derive from on an objective-c iphone game I am working on.  As I am testing for collision, I wish to set an instance of `Ball` and `Peg` appropriately depending on the actual runtime type of `actorA` or `actorB`. My code that tests this as follows:

```
// Actors that collided
        Actor *actorA = (Actor*) bodyA->GetUserData();
        Actor *actorB = (Actor*) bodyB->GetUserData();

        Ball* ball;
        Peg* peg;
        if (static_cast<Ball*> (actorA)) { // true
            ball = static_cast<Ball*> (actorA);
        }
        else if (static_cast<Ball*> (actorB)) {
            ball = static_cast<Ball*> (actorB);
        }
        if (static_cast<Peg*> (actorA)) { // also true?!
            peg = static_cast<Peg*> (actorA);
        }
        else if (static_cast<Peg*> (actorB)) {
            peg = static_cast<Peg*> (actorB);
        }
        if (peg != NULL) {
            [peg hitByBall];
        }
```

Once `ball` and `peg` are set, I then proceed to run the `hitByBall` method (objective c).

Where my problem really lies is in the casting procedurel `Ball` casts fine from `actorA`; the first `if (static_cast<>)` statement steps in and sets the `ball` pointer appropriately.

The second step is to assign the appropriate type to `peg`. I know `peg` should be a `Peg` type and I previously know it will be `actorB`, however at runtime, detecting the types, I was surprised to find actually the third `if (static_cast<>)` statement stepped in and set this, this if statement was to check if `actorA` was a `Peg`, which we already know `actorA` is a `Ball`! Why would it have stepped here and not in the fourth `if` statement?

The only thing I can assume is how casting works differently from c# and that is it finds that `actorA` which is actually of type `Ball` derives from `Actor` and then it found when  `static_cast<Peg*> (actorA)` is performed it found `Peg` derives from `Actor` too, so this is a valid test? This could all come down to how I have misunderstood the use of `static_cast`.  How can I achieve what I need? :)

I'm really uneasy about what feels to me like a long winded brute-casting attempt here with a ton of ridiculous `if` statements. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to achieve a simple cast to `Peg` and cast to `Ball` dependent on actual type held in `actorA` and `actorB`.

Hope someone out there can help! :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the return type of GetUserData()?

Comment: It will be a `Ball` or `Peg`. It can change.

Comment: `static_cast` doesn't work like that. You're mistaking `static_cast` for `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is Objective-C code (not C++, as per the title), why not just call:

```
[actorA hitByBall];
[actorB hitByBall];
```

**Updated:** If the object you are sending the message to is `nil` it will be ignored. If the object you send the message to does not implement `hitByBall`, you'll get an exception, "selector not recognized", unless you have put an empty definition in your base class (`Actor`).

You can then remove your `ball` and `peg` declarations and all of the `static_cast`s (which would have been incorrect even in C++).

Comment: Thanks Johnsy.  After re-thinking my implemention as many have suggested I agree with you, after a bit more research and realising all objective c methods are effectively 'virtual' then I can simply not implement a base method and yes as you say, just implement a hitByBall for Peg and other classes will ignore.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not true in the general case.  If an object does not implement a method, you will get a selector not recognized exception.  What you are probably both talking about is overriding the base class implementation.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP: I have clarified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To identify object type at run time you should `dynamic_cast` and not `static_cast`. But you should really reconsider your design. Probably (I don't anything about objective-c) you should make `hitByBall` a virtual method in base class and override the implementation if required in derived classes. Then you can call the method without any casts.

Comment: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'actorA' (of type 'struct Actor*') to type 'struct Ball*' (source type is not polymorphic)

Comment: can you post the declaration of struct A and struct Ball?

Comment: "Do not use dynamic_cast except in test code. If you need to know type information at runtime in this way outside of a unittest, you probably have a design flaw." - Google , in support of your suggestion to reconsider design

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I've reevaluated my approach and going with a polymorphic approach as Johnsyweb suggested.  However this still leaves me with a gripe against static_cast<T>.  Why was it returning true for both `Ball` and `Peg` when it was a `Ball` type?

Comment: `static_cast` was not returning `true`, it was returning the pointer to either `actorA` or `actorB`. Unlike `dynamic_cast`, with RTTI, no runtime checks are performed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [`-isKindOfClass`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBFBDJ). If both objects conform to the NSObject protocol, you only need to check which is of which type - the actual message passing is not limited by the static type of the pointer:

```
if (   [actorA isKindOfClass:[Peg class ]] 
    && [actorB isKindOfClass:[Ball class]]) 
{
    [actorA hitByBall];
}
else if (   [actorB isKindOfClass:[Peg class ]]
         && [actorA isKindOfClass:[Ball class]]) 
{
    [actorB hitByBall];
}
```

Comment: Well both inherit NSObject at their root level, so good point.  I did consider this, but I think after persisting with a c++ type test for some reason I never came back to it.. Thanks Georg.